# Select a table by value inside BLOB column

Tags: sql-server

We use ADO and SQL Server.

Our table has a blob column `XMLFIELD`, inside this blob we store a complete XML file with information.

```
      <XML>
          .... much much text and fields ....
     <\XML>
```

Reading and writing this XML field is no problem

How can I build a query to select only datasets whose `XMLFIELD` contains a certain Text / Word

```
select * from MyTable where XMLFIELD contains a special word
```

or

```
select * from MyTable where XMLFIELD contains a special field 
and has a special value
```

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag and added the SQL Server tag instead, because your question has zero content related to Delphi. It is strictly a SQL Server SQL question. Please use tags that are actually related to your question, so that it gets classified properly for searches and so that it gets the attention of the people most likely to be able to help you find a solution. (Also, so it doesn't get the attention of the people who look for the tags you use incorrectly when they could be using that time to help others instead.) :-) Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server has no blob data type, so what is the data type of your "blob column"? One approach would be to use the [`xml` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx) and use [XQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx); have you looked into this?